# Sim Tracking in android

Tags: android

I am doing a app on sim tracking but unable to get result

here is the main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String FILENAME = "old_file.txt";
int simstatus;
String simNo;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        if (simstatus != TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT) {
            System.out.println("--------SIM Present:" + simstatus);
            simNo = tManager.getSimSerialNumber();
            FileOutputStream fos;
            try {
                fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                fos.write(simNo.getBytes());
                System.out.println("---------Data written to files is:"
                        + simNo);
                fos.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Reciever

```
public class SimDataReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction()))  {   
            System.out.println("Reciever Started");
            Intent CompareSimServiceIntent = new Intent(context,demo.class); 
            context.startService(CompareSimServiceIntent);  
        }
    }
}
```

and the service..

```
String FILENAME = "old_file.txt";

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, final int startId) {

         Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //run your service

//                   Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                    try {
                        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(FILENAME);
                        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(fis);
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
                        String data = br.readLine();
                        System.out.println("---Data Read From File is:" + data);
                        String newsiminfo = tManager.getSimSerialNumber();
                        System.out.println("---New SIM no is:" + newsiminfo);
                        if (data.equals(tManager.getSimSerialNumber())) {
                            System.out.println("------Old sim Present:");
//                          Toast.makeText(this, "Old SIM", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        } else {
//                          Toast.makeText(this, "New SIM", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            SmsManager smsMngr = SmsManager.getDefault();
                            String destinationaddress = "8281306132";
                            String scAddress = null;
                            String text = "New Sim Is Inserted In Your Device";
                            PendingIntent sentIntent = null;
                            PendingIntent deliveryIntent = null;
                            smsMngr.sendTextMessage(destinationaddress, scAddress, text,
                                    sentIntent, deliveryIntent);
                            System.out.println("-----SMS Send");
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                }
            }, 1*60*1000);

        return startId;
    }

}
```

pls help me to find the solution....

Comment: given these permissions too  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>

Comment: why not able to get result? what error you facing?

Comment: no error but its not working after reboot

Comment: Just too much code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found similar kind of problem, when working on same kind of project.

I was also not able to track the sim after the device reboot. The problem I found here was that I was invoking the sim tracking immediately after the device reboot. But the system takes 15 to 20 seconds to load resources. The sim was not getting launched immendiately after the device reboot, so my receiver was unable to track the sim.

So, I delayed the sim tracking for 20 seconds after the device reboot. Try to delay the sim tracking and check if it works.

**Edit-**
Your Receiver should be like this,

```
public class SimDataReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            System.out.println("Reciever Started");
            Log.d("BOOT COMPLETE","Receiver Called");
            Intent CompareSimServiceIntent = new Intent(context,demo.class); 
            context.startService(CompareSimServiceIntent);  
    }
}
```

and in Manifest file, replace your code with this,

```
    <receiver android:name=".SimDataReciever" 
         android:enabled="true" 
         android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Now, check whether the messages are shown in the logcat or not.

Comment: can you post the updated code and please remove the unnecessary code from the question.

Comment: what values you are getting in **data** and **newsiminfo**.?

Comment: even the receiver is not working i tried to call a dummy activity from receiver

Comment: can you post the manifest file where you declared the reciever.?

Comment: <receiver android:name="SimDataReciever">
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action._BOOT_COMPLETED" />
             </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="demo"></service>

Comment: then why you have used the if condition in the receiver. Check my edited answer.